# How to run the Google App Engine server without restart?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine plugin with eclipse to create some web application, every time after I modify the program and run it, the modification does not take effect instantly. I have to kill the one (sometime mistakenly will kill the eclipse program) of the javaw.exe process and re-run again. Sometime it will hang at the "datanucleus enhancer".

I know it happen because the new javaw.exe run on the same port as the previous instance. But no point to kill the previous javaw.exe instance manually everytime, it is very annoying.

I thought I can save the source file and it will be automatically deploy to the development server, but it does not. What can I do so I do not have to manually kill the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run your app in debug mode-- that is, via Debug As > Web Application (rather than Run As > Web Application)-- it should reflect your changes to source. (For some changes it may need to terminate and restart the server, in which case it will notify you).

Comment: Debug mode will usually slow the execution down right? I am not setting any breakpoint in the program. I seldom use debug mode, used once or twice in Android before, the emulator become very slow, I wonder will it be the same for Google web application?